# Warning mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

Tags: php, sql

Why i have this error and how to fix this, I've double checked everything and all is okay

> **Warning**:  mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid
>   MySQL result resource in
>   **/home/sharinga/public_html/ccccc.com/app/like/like.php** on
>   line **15**
>  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'like WHERE postID='81' AND
>   userIP='2x2.2x0.x5.xxx'' at line 1

Here is sql

```
$ip_sql = mysql_query("SELECT userIP FROM like WHERE postID='$id' AND userIP='$ip'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($ip_sql) or die(mysql_error());
if($count==0)
{...
```

Comment: `if($ip_sql === FALSE){ die(mysql_error()); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LIKE` is a reserved word - escape it

```
$ip_sql = mysql_query("SELECT userIP FROM `like` WHERE postID='$id' AND userIP='$ip'");
```

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` is a keyword in SQL, use `´`

```
SELECT userIP FROM `like` WHERE postID='$id' AND userIP='$ip
```

Comment: I can't type a `´` on my keyboard :-P

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting first.  Are you looking for the null case?  If so you have to search a certain row not $count as a whole.

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
$ip_sql = mysql_query("SELECT userIP FROM like WHERE postID='$id' AND userIP='$ip'",$conn);
$count = mysql_num_rows($ip_sql) or die(mysql_error());
if ($count['postID'}==""){
}
```